# selenium logic to select 5th element of a dropdown and check for duplicate element is present in the same drop down or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("<< id exp>>")));
s.selectByIndex(5);

this is the piece of code to find 5th element of a dropdown ,what about next

Comment: What is your effort to create a logic to check duplicate elements present in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can get all the duplicate options from the dropdown.

```
List<WebElement> options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("-id-"))).getOptions();
        for(WebElement e: options) {
            System.out.println(e.getText());
        }
        Set<String> optionNames = new HashSet<String>(options.size());
        for(WebElement element: options) {
            if(optionNames.add(element.getText())==false) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate option:" +element);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No duplicate options found");
            }
        }
```